# Classification based on a list of words

Tags: r, classification

I have a dataset like this one below:

```
Id | ArticleName | Pages | Topics             | ...
1  | abcd...     | 9999  | Animals            | ...
2  | aabbcc..    | 8888  | AI, Computer, HiFi | ...
3  | aaabbb      | 7777  | Hot Dog, Animals   | ...
4  | cccbb       | 6666  | Dataset, R         | ...
5  | dddss       | 64    | Hamburger, AI      | ...
```

Each row of the ds represents an article which has, in the column **Topics**, a list of words of the topics of the article itself.

Topics have a main Area which refer to.  For example, let's say:

- Nature: (Animals, Plants)
- Technology: (Computer, HiFi, AI, Intelligent Systems, IOT, Machine Learning)
- Food: (Pizza, Fast Food, Hamburger, Hot Dog, Salad, Fries)

I've to come up with a result where if the list of topics covered by the article contains a word of the list Nature, for example, I'd have a mark (let's say 1) if the article covers >=1 arguments of the list Nature, and so on with others Areas. If no matches are found we'd have a mark in NC (Not Classified)
In other words I need a classification based on the presence of words.

Here's the example taking the ds shown up as input.

```
Id | ArticleName | Pages | Topics             | Nature | Technology | Food | NC
1  | abcd...     | 9999  | Animals            | 1      | 0          | 0    | 0
2  | aabbcc..    | 8888  | AI, Computer, HiFi | 0      | 1          | 0    | 0
3  | aaabbb      | 7777  | Hot Dog, Animals   | 1      | 0          | 1    | 0
4  | cccbb       | 6666  | Dataset, R         | 0      | 0          | 0    | 1
5  | dddss       | 64    | Hamburger, AI      | 0      | 1          | 1    | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```r
x <- "
Id | ArticleName | Pages | Topics             
1  | abcd...     | 9999  | Animals            
2  | aabbcc..    | 8888  | AI, Computer, HiFi 
3  | aaabbb      | 7777  | Hot Dog, Animals   
4  | cccbb       | 6666  | Dataset, R         
5  | dddss       | 64    | Hamburger, AI      
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(x) , header = T , sep = "|")
#===================================

Nature <- c("Animals","Plants")
Technology <- c("Computer","HiFi", "AI", "Intelligent Systems", "IOT", "Machine Learning")
Food <- c("Pizza", "Fast Food", "Hamburger", "Hot Dog", "Salad", "Fries")

cls <- matrix(0 ,nrow(df) ,4)
colnames(cls) <- c("Nature" , "Technology" ,"Food" , "NC")
i <- 1

#===================================
for(t in df$Topics) {
  x <- do.call(trimws, strsplit(t , ","))
  for (c in x) {
    if (c %in% Nature) cls[i , 1] <- 1
    else if (c %in% Technology) cls[i , 2] <- 1
    else if (c %in% Food) cls[i , 3] <- 1
    else cls[i , 4] <- 1
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
#===================================

cls
    Nature Technology Food NC
[1,]      1          0    0  0
[2,]      0          1    0  0
[3,]      1          0    1  0
[4,]      0          0    0  1
[5,]      0          1    1  0


ans <- cbind(df , cls)

ans
#>   Id   ArticleName Pages               Topics Nature Technology Food NC
#> 1  1  abcd...       9999  Animals                  1          0    0  0
#> 2  2  aabbcc..      8888  AI, Computer, HiFi       0          1    0  0
#> 3  3  aaabbb        7777  Hot Dog, Animals         1          0    1  0
#> 4  4  cccbb         6666  Dataset, R               0          0    0  1
#> 5  5  dddss           64  Hamburger, AI            0          1    1  0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I've to do the classification for something like 1.3M rows for 5 categories that contain around 20/30 words each. I tried to compute the for but the pc seems to compute forever

Comment: 1.3M row must take time , give it a try.

Comment: Tried, the matrix has 1 just in the NC column

Comment: pls `dput(head(your_data))`

Comment: Odd, because I tried your method on a simplyfied database, and it works... when in comes to the real dataset it doens't..

Comment: structure(list(Unicode = c("00101", "00101", "00101", "00101", 
"00101", "00101"), Univ = c("Torino", "Torino", "Torino", "Torino", 
"Torino", "Torino"), Accession.Number = c("WOS:A1995RF98900069", 
"WOS:000255232100042", "WOS:000258875900011", "WOS:000260047700020", 
"WOS:000258050500015", "WOS:000180390600004"), Research.Area = c("BIOCHEMISTRY & MOLECULAR BIOLOGY", 
"CRITICAL CARE MEDICINE", "INSTRUMENTS & INSTRUMENTATION", "CHEMISTRY, MULTIDISCIPLINARY", 
"ONCOLOGY", "ONCOLOGY")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: What categories you want?

Answer (score 0):

Based on data on comments

```r
df <- structure(list(Unicode = c("00101", "00101", "00101", "00101", "00101", "00101"),
                     Univ = c("Torino", "Torino", "Torino", "Torino", "Torino", "Torino"),
                     Accession.Number = c("WOS:A1995RF98900069", "WOS:000255232100042", "WOS:000258875900011", "WOS:000260047700020", "WOS:000258050500015", "WOS:000180390600004"),
                     Research.Area = c("BIOCHEMISTRY & MOLECULAR BIOLOGY", "CRITICAL CARE MEDICINE", "INSTRUMENTS & INSTRUMENTATION", "CHEMISTRY, MULTIDISCIPLINARY", "ONCOLOGY", "ONCOLOGY")),
                     row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")


library(qdapTools)
lst <- lapply(df$Research.Area ,
                function(t) do.call(trimws, strsplit(t , "[,&]")))

HotEnc <- mtabulate(lst)
HotEnc

#>   BIOCHEMISTRY CHEMISTRY CRITICAL CARE MEDICINE INSTRUMENTATION INSTRUMENTS
#> 1            1         0                      0               0           0
#> 2            0         0                      1               0           0
#> 3            0         0                      0               1           1
#> 4            0         1                      0               0           0
#> 5            0         0                      0               0           0
#> 6            0         0                      0               0           0
#>   MOLECULAR BIOLOGY MULTIDISCIPLINARY ONCOLOGY
#> 1                 1                 0        0
#> 2                 0                 0        0
#> 3                 0                 0        0
#> 4                 0                 1        0
#> 5                 0                 0        1
#> 6                 0                 0        1
```

then you can sum `(HotEnc$cat1 + HotEnc$cat2)/2` to make it in one category.

<sup>Created on 2022-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I ran out of memory, I think it's better the first solution. Let's suppose that the lists of categories are; A=("BIOCHEMISTRY & MOLECULAR BIOLOGY", "CRITICAL CARE MEDICINE") B=""INSTRUMENTS & INSTRUMENTATION", "CHEMISTRY, MULTIDISCIPLINARY"), C=("ONCOLOGY"). Then I'll adjust for my datas (i can't write real categories here bacause of the  maximum length of a comment. Tried to adapt the code of the first solution with my real datas but don't know why doesn't work honestly.

Comment: are A , B , C only the categories in df$Research.Area ?

Comment: Done! Didn't know that R finds difference between strings in CAPS LOCK and dont! Than you so much, so much helpful!!

Comment: i used your first solution, but I changed the topics in the different list of categories I had to generate from "Art" in "ART" for example.

Comment: Pleasure to help ...